# PHP output buffering displaying first 2 values together

Tags: php, buffer, output-buffering

I am trying to get my PHP script to print its data in realtime using output buffering. For example, I have attached code for a loop that counts to 50, with a sleep delay of 1. 
 I would expect it to display and count it like such [echo 0, sleep 1, echo 1, sleep 1, echo 2, sleep 1, echo 3, sleep 1, echo 4, sleep 1, ... etc]. (counting like a human) 
However, for the initial 2 values (value 0 and 1), they appear together immediately. There is no buffer delay between the first 2 values, and they are outputted together. It doesnt echo 0 then delay 1 sec, then echo 1, delay 1... etc. 
It outputs value 0 and value 1, and works how I would expect it to after the initial 2 values.

Why is it outputting the first 2 values of the loop together?

```
<?php
header('Content-Encoding: none;');
    set_time_limit(0);
for($i=0;$i<50;$i++)
    {
    if (ob_get_level() == 0){ob_start();}
        echo $i."<br/>";
        echo str_pad('', 4096);
        ob_flush();
        flush();
        sleep(1);
    ob_end_flush();
    }
?>
```

Comment: This behaviour of printing one thing after the other greatly depends on all kinds of undefined behaviours of Browser, PHP, WebServer and all Infrastructure in between. You should not depend on it. I would use AJAX instead.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, how would you code that simple loop in ajax?